# Play Framework seems to be caching GET results

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm using Play Framework 2.3.8 (was on 2.2.4 with the same issue, upgrading didn't help).

I'm not using Play Framework's Cache API. But it seems like GET results are still somehow being strangely cached by Play.

For example, if I hit api GET `/api/GetPurchases`, I'll get 2 results. Play will log that the `GetPurchases` api has been hit (and I also override `OnRouteRequest` in `Global.java` and log it there). Then I'll hit api POST `/api/CreatePurchase` and confirm that in the database there are now 3 purchase objects.

I'll call GET `/api/GetPurchases` again and I'll get 2 results. And the logs show that it's as if the api `/api/GetPurchases` was never hit.

Also, this only happens when my app is deployed to Heroku. Locally everything works perfectly. But I've spoken with Heroku support to ensure that Heroku is platform-only and they would never cause Play to act any differently.

Comment: Are you running them in the same mode in both scenarios? If so use something like Chrome or Firefox developer tools to inspect the HTTP headers that are sent by your Play app

Comment: @Salem Hi Salem, I'm testing it as we speak, it's actually behaving (still weirdly) but a bit better in a browser than in my iOS app. In my browser at least every time I call an API, Play is logging that it's hit. But often it still gets incorrect data (just the last data that was successfully sent to my iOS app). But the fact that none of these issues are reproduce-able in a local environment is so strange.

Comment: @Salem it's always sending a 200 OK response header when I look at my iOS app results. Even though Play logs don't show the API ever hit. Also, we have an Android app that's showing the same erroneous behavior, so it seems to be more likely a server-side issue.

Comment: @Salem well Salem you were absolutely right, and as I expected from the question title, Play was caching responses and the server response was a 304. It was not reproduce-able from Chrome because I think Chrome adds a dummy variable to requests. It was not reproduce-able from my iOS app because the AFNetworkingLibrary I was using was falsely telling me that it was a 200 response from 30 minutes ago instead of a 304 response. It was only on our Android that we saw the true 304 response and were able to fix it. Tough one, spent 2 full days on that...

Comment: You can try to use `response().setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");` in your controller or append the current timestamp in the device as a get parameter(ex: `yourserver.com/api/GetPurchases?ts=1425130064`). I think Play has a config to completely disable caching, but that may not be the best option...

Comment: @Salem create an answer please, so OP can accept your help

Comment: @Salem Yeah we already implemented that and it solved it perfectly. Please submit an answer and I will accept. By default, Play Framework caches stuff in production mode (so when deployed to Heroku) but doesn't in development mode (so when deployed locally)

Comment: Don't forget you can always run `foreman start` to get a production-like instance running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually found that Play Framework was caching GET results.

We found that by default, Play does not cache results in development mode (so when deployed locally). But in production mode (so when deployed to Heroku), Play does cache results by default.

To change this, we added this line of code in our action methods where we didn't want Play to cache the results:

```
response().setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");
```

It can also be helpful to locally mock a production deployment by running `foreman start`.

**thanks to Salem and millhouse from comments above**